# Do not allow the application to be authenticated after the email verifcation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a login and register form. when the user registers he will be redirected to a new page where he will get a success message and an option to resend an email. after verification, the user is redirected back to the home page as a default behavior. but I wanted the user to be redirected to the login page after email verification.

In the verification controller, I have changed redirect URL like

```
 protected $redirectTo = '/login';
```

It will redirect to the login page after verification. but if I try to access other routes it will take me to the particular page because the user is authenticated when he verified.

how can I avoid the user to be authenticated at the time of verification? or how can I protect my routes from the user without login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just force a logout before the redirect to the login page:

```
Auth::logout()
```

Comment: the verification email is sending successfully in my local environment using mail trap. what changes should be made if I want this to be worked in the server when I hosted? the email should be sent to their mail id instead of mailtrap.